# javascript contact form validation using $.ajax behaving funny

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, validation

I made a contact form, and now I want to validate it before sending the message. The validation works if all fields are empty, i.e. the form doesn't submit anything, which is fine.

**1st scenario:** But when all fields have the correct information except for the **email** and **phone** fields **only**, which use regular expressions, and the form is submitted, it still goes to `$.ajax()`. And I pretty sure that in my code, if the information doesn't match the RegEx then `return false`, so it shouldn't even carry on to the `$.ajax()`. But it's still does... Weird!

**2nd scenario:** In addition , when it goes to `$.ajax()`, it fails, returning an error.

**3rd scenario:** Or when all fields are filled with the correct information from the 1st time the page loads, and the form is submitted, there's an error that says `{"error": "Please use POST request"}` or I get `Error 405`. But I'm using `POST` in the `$.ajax()`... What's wrong with the 'POST'?

Please view my code here (I have included and commented the PHP email code, at the top of the HTML, just in case you wanna test it in some server ):

http://jsfiddle.net/qvSaW/3/

I know there are plugins around but I'm not allowed to use any plugins...

Many thanks

Comment: I am not able to recreate first scenario. It kind of works correct.

p.s. you can add a server response in jsfiddle . See the `Ajax Requests` in left panel.

Comment: Thanks @Jashwant, but you have to fill all the fields correctly, except for the email and phone fields (e.g. don't type email and numbers...)

Comment: I think you have to provide absolute URL for this to get the fiddle working     url:'script/sendmail.php',

Comment: @MarmiK, The PHP is not the issue, the JavaScript is. I just added the PHP just for convenience purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) it covers validation with special rules, messages and finally you can submit if it passes all.

Comment: Thanks @Andres but no plugin allowed.